QNX Momentics IDE won't connect to Qemu virtual target (Linux host)
I'm trying to set up the dev environment for QNX SDP 8 in Linux. But for some reason I can't get the virtual target to work.
I sourced the QNX env script and called the check-net script before starting the Momentics IDE.
The check-net scripta sets up a br0 bridge adapter.
Then I created the virtual target using the IDE.
I created a Qemu x86 vm which is created successfully and a terminal is connected in the IDE.
But the target viewer only says "connection lost, invalid target configuration". And I can't get my project to run on the target.
What am I missing? Do I need to do any additional configuration to the br or tap adapter? Is there any configuration in the IDE I need to change?

Ok. So... after starting virtqemud and virtnetworkd
sudo systemctl start virtqemud.socket
sudo systemctl start virtnetworkd.socket

And then adding this to the Extra Options: field when creating the virtual environment
--ssh-ident=prompt

It now works like a charm.
I also enabled virtqemud and virtnetworkd to make those services start at  boot.
sudo systemctl enable virtqemud.socket
sudo systemctl enable virtnetworkd.socket

Edit:
I need to run the Virt UI client everytime before starting Momentics. Otherwise the virtual network is not available.

Not a complete answer. But at least I gotten the network to work. What I needed to do was to make sure virtqemud.socket and virtnetworkd.socket was running before creating the virtual target.
I did this by running these lines before creating the virtual target.
sudo systemctl start virtqemud.socket
sudo systemctl start virtnetworkd.socket

After that I can log onto the qnx virtual machine with ssh by using the ip address on the virbr0 adapter which is automatically available after starting virtqemud.socket and virtnetworkd.socket
The login on qnx is in this case root with the password root
ssh root@192.168.122.179

But I still get "Invalid target settings" in the Momentics IDE, though. And trying to run the code on the virtual target gives me a dialog box saying "Target is not connected: vm1".
So if anyone has any answer about what settings might be wrong and how to connect my project to the virtual target, that would be highly appreciated.
